# Every positive definite matrix can be written as $B^TB$ for some invertible $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix. Show that there exists an invertible matrix $B$ such that $A=B^TB$. [Hint: Use the Spectral Theorem to write $A = QDQ^T$. Then show that D can be factored as $C^TC$ for some invertible matrix $C$.]

I can't seem to get to the correct answer. I'm not entirely sure what is meant by the last line of the hint too. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Consider the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the square roots of the diagonal elements of $\mathbf D$.

Comment: $B=Q^T D^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: @Learner, how did you get to this answer?

Comment: cruise: start from my hint.

Comment: As in J.M. comment, write $C$ to be the diagonal matrix with square roots of the entries of the diagonal of $D$.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, so you take $B^T=B$ to be $\sqrt{D}$?

Comment: That isn't it. You have the decomposition from the "spectral theorem"; replace $\mathbf D$ with $\sqrt{\mathbf D}\sqrt{\mathbf D}$. Remember that $(\mathbf A\mathbf B)^\top=\mathbf B^\top\mathbf A^\top$...

Comment: @J.M. Ah, I see how it works now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Learner Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$A$ is symmetric, so it can be written as $A=QDQ^T$ (Eigenvalue decomposition of a symmetric matrix), where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with real elements on main diagonal.

$A$ is PSD, so elements on main diagonal of $D$ are nonnegative, so they have square root. Let $D= D_1D_1^T$, where $D_1$ is also diagonal.

You can write $C^T= QD_1$. You will have $A=C^TC$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, that's excactly what I needed :).

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you know [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)? You can even chose $B$ as a triangular matrix.

If you don't like an abstract proof you just can compute it, for example 
$$\begin{pmatrix} l_{11} & 0 \\
l_{21} & l_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} l_{11} & l_{21}\\
0 & l_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{12} & a_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
when you chose $l_{ii}>0$ you will always have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ equations and unknowns, hence a unique solution exists.

To get the Cholesky decomposition from the eigenvalue decomposition we use an lu dcomposition, as $Q$ is invertible we know that $Q=L\cdot U$ for some normed lower triangular matrix $L$, and some upper triangular matrix $U$.
So 
$$A= Q^T  D Q = U^T L^T  D L U $$
As $U^T$ and $U$ are invertible we have
$$U^{T^{-1}} A U^{-1}=L^T  D L $$
We see that 
$$U^{T^{-1}} A U^{-1}$$
is symmetric and positiv definit iff $A$ is symmetric and positiv definit, and we can get any positive definite matrix, hence we get the cholesky decomposition.

Comment: No, I don't. Could you show me how that would be done?

Comment: I'd sure like to see somebody derive the Cholesky triangle from an eigendecomposition...

Comment: @J.M. oh from an eigendecomposition. that is not so obvious, but let me try it

Comment: Thats a whole other way of thinking. Thanks for the insight :).

Comment: @J.M. added it, hope everything works

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
D=\mbox{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_n) \quad\mbox{and}\quad U=\mbox{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1}, \ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n}).
$$
So check it yourself $B=QU$.