# How to prove $C$ is invertible?

Tags: matrices, inverse, positive-definite

How does one prove that the matrix $C$ from user25004's answer is invertible? [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356082/every-positive-definite-matrix-can-be-written-as-btb-for-some-invertible-b)

Comment: It is the product of two invertible matrices.

Comment: @tangentbundle Ah yes, i see, cheers